# How can I map multiple Boolean properties into single SQLAlchemy column of binary type?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

How can I map multiple Boolean properties into single SQLAlchemy column?

I have a class kind of `flags` :

```
class Thing(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    isEnabled = db.Column(db.Boolean, nullable=False, default=False)
    isAdministrator = db.Column(db.Boolean, nullable=False, default=False)
    isPasswordExpired = db.Column(db.Boolean, nullable=False, default=False)
    isEmailConfirmed = db.Column(db.Boolean, nullable=False, default=False)
    isPhoneConfirmed = db.Column(db.Boolean, nullable=False, default=False)
    # ... many more booleans #
```

I'd like to store them into single `db.Column(db.Integer)` or something like that small field.

Could you help me with example of how should I do this?

---

Please don't try to get logic of those fields or help me to store password expiration mark better - this is an example.

Comment: Do you search for a postgresql logic? Are you fine with managing them in python?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest
1) There is a second, almost unmanaged app that requires bitfield of those.
2) To keep things smaller
3) once defined with contract `Enabled in bit 3`, it will never be changed, for compatibility, only new "significant bits" can be added.

Comment: @kosciej16, no, I am looking how to do it in python or ORM way, without diving into specific db engine

Answer (score 1):

You can use an [`enum.IntFlag`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html#enum.IntFlag) to store all those flags in a single `Integer` field.

```py
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import declarative_base, Session
from enum import IntFlag, auto

class UserFlag(IntFlag):
    ENABLED = auto()
    ADMINISTRATOR = auto()
    PASSWORD_EXPIRED = auto()
    EMAIL_CONFIRMED = auto()
    PHONE_CONFIRMED = auto()

Base = declarative_base()

class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = "user"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    user_flags = Column(Integer, nullable=False)

engine = create_engine("sqlite://", future=True, echo=True)

Base.metadata.create_all(engine)

session = Session(bind=engine)

admin = User(user_flags = UserFlag.ENABLED | UserFlag.ADMINISTRATOR)
ljmc = User(user_flags = UserFlag.ENABLED | UserFlag.PASSWORD_EXPIRED)

session.add(admin)
session.add(ljmc)
session.commit()

bool(admin.user_flags & UserFlag.ADMINISTRATOR)  # True
bool(ljmc.user_flags & UserFlag.ADMINISTRATOR)  # False
```

You can also set a helper method to check the flags:

```py
    def is_user_flag_set(self, flag: UserFlag) -> bool:
        return self.user_flags & flag != 0
```

usage

```py
admin.is_user_flag_set(UserFlag.ADMINISTRATOR)  # True
```

Comment: Does SQLAlchemy works good with IntFlag type?

Comment: `IntFlag` is also an `int` so, no problem storing it as `Integer`.